# Selection of certain elements within CSS style class

Tags: html, css

My goal was to create two tables, with slight difference between them. I don't know if it's uncommon, or I don't even know how to look for it, but my try was this:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .tabelka1 *
        {
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .tabelka2 table, th, td
        {
            border: 4px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

This one works, but just because there's no input elements within it, and it's first in order.

```
.tabelka1 table, th, td
```

would be perfect, but it makes both have 4px borders. 
Whole table is then put inside `<div class="tabelka1">`, and closed, of course.
 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.tabelka1 table,.tabelka1 th,.tabelka1 td{
  your style
}
.tabelka2 table,.tabelka2 th,.tabelka2 td{
  your style
}
```